# Postgres change number format

Tags: postgresql

in Postgres I use this query:

```
UPDATE managers SET phone_number = replace(phone_number, '\m86', '3706');
```

unfortunately the field is long and query fails. I need to change all numbers beginning with 86 to start with 3706...

I tried many Postgres functions, but it is not obvious do they have the fumction I need.

the error is:

```
ERROR:  function replace(bigint, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE managers SET phone_number = replace(phone_number, '\m...
                                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.managers(
  phone_number bigint,
  email_report boolean,
)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? The query looks correct (although the \ looks wrong in the search string)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I don't think you want to use a replace here, because it  will make changes all over the place. A regexp_replace would be better suited, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, if you use a regex replace it becomes much easier to articulate what a number is which starts with `86`.  The pattern for that is just `^86` and the replacement is `3706`.  Consider the following query:

```
UPDATE managers
SET phone_number = REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number::text, '^86', '3706')::int
```